# Perl CGI Table creation with foreach

Tags: perl, foreach, cgi

I just played around with Perl CGI and SQLite.  I thought something like this could do the job.

```
my $res = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT name, surename, phone FROM status;"),
print $cgi->table(
$cgi->Tr(
    { -align => "CENTER", -valign => "TOP" },
    $cgi->th( [ 'Name', 'Surename', 'Phone' ] )
),
foreach my $row (@$res){
    ( $name, $surename, $phone ) = @$row,
    print $cgi->Tr( $cgi->td($name), $cgi->td($surename), $cgi->td($phone) ),
  }
);
```

Is it required to create the HTML document's table manually?

Answer (score 1):

You should familiarize yourself with the [POD for the CGI module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI).  Therein you'll find an example of table creation:

```
print table({-border=>undef},
           caption('When Should You Eat Your Vegetables?'),
           Tr({-align=>'CENTER',-valign=>'TOP'},
           [
              th(['Vegetable', 'Breakfast','Lunch','Dinner']),
              td(['Tomatoes' , 'no', 'yes', 'yes']),
              td(['Broccoli' , 'no', 'no',  'yes']),
              td(['Onions'   , 'yes','yes', 'yes'])
           ]
           )
        );
```

As you can see from the example, you do need to specify the ingredients that go into the table.  The CGI module's HTML tag helpers aren't really magic; they're just Perl functions (or methods depending on how you use the module) that closely mirror the HTML they represent.  If you would have to type `<table><tr><th>...` in HTML, your tag helpers will need to be `table`, `Tr`, and `th`, etc.  Using a combination of tags or tag helpers in a loop is just fine, as long as the HTML that gets output is comprehensible to browsers.

Scripts that use the CGI module can be run from the command line, which is an excellent debugging tool since they will dump the raw HTML do the screen for you to review.

Comment: It's really a much better idea to use a proper templating system for this sort of thing, though.

Comment: Agreed, and while we're at it, a modern lightweight framework that can interface with CGI yet facilitate a more maintainable separation of concerns (Mojolicious with it's Mojolicious::Lite is a good starting point, or Dancer).  Naked CGI refuses to disappear, but it's becoming less relevant all the time.

Comment: Somwhat related, but slightly OT: I've lately found that writing the HTML (especially tables) can be heavily sped up with a [zen coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) plugin for your text editor. For use with a template engine or framework, this makes hacking the HTML in really speedy.

Comment: @electronico Just following up a couple weeks later to see if this explanation was helpful to you.  If not, let me know what more I can do by way of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a resounding NO. These two lines of code:

```
my $cats = $db->selectall_arrayref("select * from pubs..authors");
print map { $q->Tr(undef, $q->td($_)) ."\n"} @$cats;
```

will gives you (well, me ..)

```
<tr><td>172-32-1176</td> <td>White</td> <td>Johnson</td> <td>408 496-7223</td>     <td>10932 Bigge Rd.</td> <td>Menlo Park</td> <td>CA</td> <td>94025</td> <td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>213-46-8915</td> <td>Green</td> <td>Marjorie</td> <td>415 986-7020</td> <td>309 63rd St. #411</td> <td>Oakland</td> <td>CA</td> <td>94618</td> <td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>238-95-7766</td> <td>Carson</td> <td>Cheryl</td> <td>415 548-7723</td> <td>589 Darwin Ln.</td> <td>Berkeley</td> <td>CA</td> <td>94705</td> <td>1</td></tr>
.... and however many more authors from pubs
```

For completeness, with hashref, you can pull out the headers like so

```
my $cats = $db->selectall_hashref("select * from pubs..authors", [ au_id]);

my @rows = values %$cats; # array of hashes now

print $q->Tr(undef, $q->th([keys( %$rows[0] )])),"\n"; #borrow keys from first guy 
print map { $q->Tr(undef, $q->td( [ values(%$_) ] ) ),"\n"; }  @rows;
```